# How to solve "setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnKeyListener(){})" error on android?

Tags: android

I'm getting an error with this message "The method setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnKeyListener(){})"

How can I overcome this problem?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_app);

    ListView myListView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);

    final EditText myEditText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);

   final ArrayList<String> toDolist =new ArrayList<String>();

    final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

    aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,toDolist);

    myListView.setAdapter(aa);

    myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)

                if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER){
                    toDolist.add(0,myEditText.getText().toString());

                    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    myEditText.setText("");

                    return true;
                }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change `setOnKeyListener` as :

```
myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

              // your code here 
        }
    });
```

or import  `android.view.View.OnKeyListener` package to set `OnKeyListener` for EditText

Answer (score 0):

try
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;

instead of
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnKeyListener;